# Kivy FBO access Z Buffer

Tags: 3d, glsl, kivy, buffer, lighting

When creating an fbo in kivy, it accepts "with_depthbuffer" as an argument. In the documentation, it says that this will cause the fbo to be allocated with a z buffer. I would like to try using this for lighting effects.

My question is, where can I find and use that buffer? 
I have the option to clear it, but looking in the source code for that isn't helpful.
I noticed that fbo.texture has a bufferfmt attribute. Is the depth buffer stored in the image texture? Can I access that in glsl to get the depth of the pixel?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I found a kind of "hacky" way of saving the depth information by assigning gl_FragColor to vec4(lambert_value, -1.0 / vertex_pos.z, 1.0, 1.0) and using those values in post-processing. But obviously i can't use this in an actual application

EDIT:

Ok, so I guess the temporary way I came up with seems pretty accurate to how its done.

I visited this page: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/fbo.pyx
and at line 230, a render buffer is being bound if with_depthbuffer == True.

I looked up what a render buffer is and apparently they cannot be used other than in the current shader pass. Which means that my goal of getting that information from the fbo wasn't going to work.

Then I realised that I will never need the depth information from the camera's point of view, only the light. So I just generate the depth information using the light's shader. I feel stupid. But thats kinda how these things go. I think I can figure this out. I'll keep updating this page just so there's a little more information out there. Thanks for reading

If you want to test it out, just click/drag to change the light position.
There are also commented lines that use my temporary approach to saving the depth information so you can see kind of what i'm going for.
You'll also need some sort of object file, I used the blender monkey

main.py

```
post_shader = '''
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

/* Outputs from the vertex shader */
varying vec4 frag_color;
varying vec2 tex_coord0;

/* uniform texture samplers */
uniform sampler2D texture0;

uniform vec2 mouse_pos;

void main(void)
{
    float distance = length(gl_FragCoord.xy - mouse_pos) * .02;
    vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture0, tex_coord0);
    vec3 color = pixel.rgb / distance;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);

    // uncomment for desired results
    // float brightness = clamp(pixel.r / distance, .1, .8) * pixel.g;
    // gl_FragColor = vec4(brightness, brightness, brightness, 1.0);
}
'''


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.resources import resource_find
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics.opengl import *
from kivy.graphics import *
from objloader import ObjFile


class Renderer(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.canvas = RenderContext(use_parent_projection=True)
        # self.canvas.shader.fs = resource_find('post_shader.glsl')
        self.canvas.shader.fs = post_shader

        scene = ObjFile(resource_find("Models/monkey.obj"))
        m = list(scene.objects.values())[0]

        self.z_pos = 0
        self.d = 1

        super(Renderer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            self.fbo = Fbo(compute_normal_matrix=True,
                           with_depthbuffer=True)
            self.fbo.shader.source = resource_find('simple.glsl')
            self.display = Rectangle()

        with self.fbo:
            self.cb = Callback(self.setup_gl_context)
            ClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0)
            ClearBuffers(clear_depth=True)

            PushMatrix()
            self.translation = Translate(0, 0, -3)
            self.rot = Rotate(1, 0, 1, 0)

            UpdateNormalMatrix()
            Color(rgb=(0, 0, 0))
            self.mesh = Mesh(vertices=m.vertices,
                             indices=m.indices,
                             fmt=m.vertex_format,
                             mode='triangles')

            PopMatrix()
            self.cb = Callback(self.reset_gl_context)

        self.display.texture = self.fbo.texture

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 60.)

    def setup_gl_context(self, *args):
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)

    def reset_gl_context(self, *args):
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.canvas['mouse_pos'] = touch.pos

    def update(self, dt):
        self.z_pos += self.d * dt
        if self.d > 0:
            if self.z_pos > -2:
                self.d *= -1
        elif self.z_pos < -15:
            self.d *= -1
        self.translation.z = self.z_pos
        self.rot.angle += dt * 10

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.display.size = self.size
        self.fbo['projection_mat'].perspective(90, self.width / float(self.height), .1, 25)


class RendererApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout()
        root.add_widget(Renderer())

        return root


if __name__ == "__main__":
    RendererApp().run()
```

simple.glsl

```
/* simple.glsl

simple diffuse lighting based on laberts cosine law; see e.g.:
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law
*/

---VERTEX SHADER-------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
#endif

attribute vec3  v_pos;
attribute vec3  v_normal;

uniform mat4 modelview_mat;
uniform mat4 projection_mat;

varying vec4 normal_vec;
varying vec4 vertex_pos;

void main (void) {
    //compute vertex position in eye_space and normalize normal vector
    vec4 pos = modelview_mat * vec4(v_pos,1.0);
    vertex_pos = pos;
    normal_vec = vec4(v_normal, 0.0);
    gl_Position = projection_mat * pos;
}


---FRAGMENT SHADER-----------------------------------------------------
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
#endif

varying vec4 normal_vec;
varying vec4 vertex_pos;

uniform mat4 normal_mat;

void main (void){
    //correct normal, and compute light vector (assume light at the eye)
    vec4 v_normal = normalize( normal_mat * normal_vec ) ;
    vec4 v_light = normalize( vec4(0,0,0,1) - vertex_pos );
    //reflectance based on lamberts law of cosine
    float theta = clamp(dot(v_normal, v_light), 0.0, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(theta, theta, theta, 1.0);

//    uncomment for desired results
//    gl_FragColor = vec4(theta, -3.0 / vertex_pos.z, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to get depthmap from fbo to make shadow mapping but there isn't function to get depthmap.I think we can edit source and make a function to get depthmap from fbo....i edited source but kivy source files are compiled so we need to compile it too....i'm also making game engine in kivy which got objects loading,texture loading,shaders ,animation realtime,normal mapping,collision system (from scratch) and multiple light system too ... here is the link: https://youtu.be/K5gTYC7sLVc  ....I think we can make kivy much more better and it will be helpful for many python developers who are willing to develop game with python and want to export to mobile platform too..